# Aristotelian technique of bootstrapping into new areas of knowledge

Tags: aristotle

In "Zen and the Art of Motorcycle Maintenance", the author mentions Aristotelian techniques of bootstrapping into new areas of knowledge (Chapter 29, page 356). What does he mean?

Comment: Can you provide the passage in which this occurs?

Comment: No, edit the question you posted, and provide the passage so others have the surrounding context.

Comment: Hello. Can you quote the passage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrapping generally means the evolvement of things without the need of an additional external influence or input by a simple...let's say "algorithm".

An aristotalian deduction (as most philosophy, I think) usually starts by a normal fact analyzing its conditions by "thinking it right", that is following the rules of logic most prominently established (rather: written down) by himself. By this, you get step by step a deeper insight of what it means to be/do this and that.

I think the author called it specifically Aristotelian because he is thought to be the first who did this in such a systematic manner for almost everything that occured in his life.